# How to give a daemon thread a stop event

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, deque

I am trying to get my head around threading in python, I have pieced together a simple tkinter UI that can run a background task to better understand how it all works.
I seem to have got to the point where I can create a seperate thread and interact with the GUI but the problem comes when I try to carry out the task the second time.

I believe what I am missing is a way to tell the daemon when to stop the thread.
Here is my code thus far:

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from collections import deque
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
from time import sleep


class Emitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.emit_text)
        self.running = False

    def emit_text(self):
        sleep(3)
        messageQueue.append(f'Random number: {randint(0, 100)}')
        # self.thread.set()

    def start_emit(self):
        ui.consume_text()
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()


class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text='Original text')
        self.label.pack()
        start = tk.Button(self.root, text='Start Download', command=lambda x=Emitter(): x.start_emit())
        start.pack()

    def consume_text(self):
        try:
            self.label['text'] = messageQueue.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            self.root.after(ms=1000, func=self.consume_text)


messageQueue = deque()
ui = UI()
ui.root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to understand other answers but I can't grasp how you tell the daemon/thread what it's condition to stop is.
The prgram works as intended the first time you click the button, but then if you try to click it again it gives the error `RuntimeError: cannot set daemon status of active thread` even if I have waited for the Emitter to finish it's task

Comment: I am pretty sure you only want a Daemon thread when its for something you don't intend to stop with a condition other than the program terminating.  Its usually used for a thread that's less important or for background tasks and stops when the program is stopped.  Maybe you just want to use a non daemon thread and then you have the ability to do what you are asking with `start()` and `join()`. Look at this [explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: FYI: A `Thread` object can only be used one time. Each time you want to start a new thread, you must create a new `Thread(...)`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ahh that's it! Because I made the thread static it wasn't stopping. Now that I've changed that the threads are stopping properly. I'll post an answer below

Comment: I think my understanding of the word static is wrong, I should have said  'Because I made the thread a permanent instance of the Emitter class the thread would never stop.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Solomon Slow for their comment, the problem I had was I was trying to restart the thread but in fact I should have been creating a new one each time.
To fix the problem, I changed my class Emitter class to create a new thread each time start_emit() is called.

The fixed class:

```
class Emitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()

    def emit_text(self):
        sleep(3)
        messageQueue.append(f'Random number: {randint(0, 100)}')

    def start_emit(self):
        ui.consume_text()
        thread = Thread(target=self.emit_text)
        thread.start()
```

I also removed the `self.thread.setDaemon(True)` line.